Claimable balance, where are these funds in holding?
creating a claimable balance for another party, where once funds leave my account do these funds go while waiting to be claimed by claimant ?   Like a cashiers check, the money is removed from your account and is held in a third parties account waiting for "pay to order" to claim the amount..
There must be another account with public key associated to it around somewhere....
Or how does this work, to hold the tokens outside of your account?
